# Is there a way to make Windows 8.1 (home edition) request a periodic password change?

Tags: windows-8.1, password-management

Is there a way to get Windows 8.1 (home edition) to request/require a periodic password change (period settable by the user)?

If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Non Home Edition Users**

Open Local Security Policy by typing the Start menu search box, type `secpol.msc` into the search box, and then click `secpol`.‌ Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

In the left pane, double-click `Account Policies`, and then click `Password Policy`.

Double-click the item in the Policy list that you want to change, change the setting, and then click `OK`.
The setting you are looking for is `Maximum password age`.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-password-policy-settings#1TC=windows-7)

**For Home Edition Users**

Unfortunately, for home edition users, secpol doesn't exist on Home editions. For those you'll need to do this (from an administrator command prompt; right click the command prompt shortcut and select `Run as Administrator`):

Enable Password Expiration:

```
wmic path Win32_UserAccount where Name='username' set PasswordExpires=true
```

Replace, `username` with the user you want to have this work for.

To view the current settings use:

```
net accounts
```

To update a setting, use:

```
net accounts /maxpwage:42
```

[Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73224-password-expiration-change-max-min-password-age.html)

Comment: secpool.msc isn't present on non-Professional versions of Windows 8.1

Comment: Cool. I particularly appreciate that you gave steps *and* source!